# Ruby on Rails User total credits

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have two models and i am trying to show the told credits of a user on the index view.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many  :credits



class Credit < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
```

I am trying to display the total credits of users on the index.html.erb view. I have created a helper method.

```
module UsersHelper

 def designer_owed
    designer_owed = Credit.where( :user_id => @user ).sum(:total_received)
  end
```

The results i get are a bit confusing, i know i am doing something wrong but i can't figure it out.

**index.html.erb**

```
<%= h number_to_currency(designer_owed, :unit => "$") %>
```

I get a zero.

but on my **show.html.erb**

**<%= h number_to_currency(designer_owed, :unit => "$") %>**

I get the right total.  My sql looks like this when i query using the index.html.erb

```
SELECT SUM("credits"."total_received") AS sum_id FROM "credits" WHERE "credits"."user_id" IS NULL
```

I would like to show this on the index view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def index
  @users = User.includes(:credits) #fires 2 queries. for users and for credits. use for code optimization
end
```

in view, do

```
%table
  %thead
    %tr 
      %th User
      %th Credits
  %tbody
    - @users.each do |user|
      %tr
        %td user.name
        %td user.credits.collect(&:total_recieved).sum #doesnt fire extra query cause we have used 'includes'
```

checkout http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Answer (score 1):

Inside your views, instance variables like '@user' correspond to the instance variables in your controller.

In your index controller, and corresponding view, you would normally have an '@users' instance variable containing all of your users. In fact, in many cases an index action can be as simple as:

```
def index
  @users = User.all
end
```

In any case, it would be unusual to have an @user variable inside your index - and it seems that you don't, hence the error you've been getting.

In your index view, I imagine you want to iterate through all of your users and display the amount owed for each, so:

```
<%= h @users.each {|user| number_to_currency(designer_owed(user), :unit => "$") %>
```

My erb is somewhat rusty as I've been using Haml for ages now but I think this should work. You'll want to alter it to meet your layout needs.

Your helper method now takes in a user argument:

```
def designer_owed(user)
  Credit.where( :user => user ).sum(:total_received)
end
```